# Show that $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ in the uniform norm but does converge on the norm $||f||=\sqrt{\int_a^b|f(x)|^2}dx$

Tags: normed-spaces, uniform-convergence, supremum-and-infimum

Bounded on $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R},$

$$
f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
 1-nx&\text{if}\, 0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}\\
      1&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I think for the first part I need to show that the $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$ of the supremum of $f_n-f$ does not equal 0 since that is a condition of uniform convergence on the uniform norm.

I am given that $f(x)=1$ pointwise as $n\rightarrow \infty$, so I tried to find the supremum and got

$$
||f_n(x)-f||=\sup
\begin{cases}
 nx&\text{if}\, 0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}\}
=1
$$

Is this correct? How do i go from here to the next part?

Comment: $f_n\to \boldsymbol 1_{[0,1)}(x)$ which is not continuous on $[0,1]$. Therefore the convergence is not uniform. For the $L^2$ convergence, notice that $$\int_0^1|f_n-f|^2=n^2\int_0^{1/n}x^2\,\mathrm d x=...$$

Comment: @Surb how can I show that $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ in the uniform norm?

Comment: you already did, since uniform convergence implies $\|f-f_n\|\to 0$

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it @Exodd

Comment: Hi @Surb What is the meaning of $\mathbf 1_{[0,1)}()$? Why is this not continuous on [0,1]? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @learningmaths: $$\boldsymbol 1_{[0,1)}(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in [0,1)\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ which is clearly not continuous on $[0,1]$.